# Position bar left within center tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress

Within my index.html, I have created the following div, which is located within the center tag.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bar">
    <span class="bar-fill"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This looks like this on the page: **[Progress Bar Image]**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFvwD.png)

I would like the blue bar, to be positioned to the left of this container.

Below is my CSS:

```
/* Progress Bar */
.container {
width: 400px;
}

.bar {
width: 100%;
background: #eee;
padding: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.bar-fill {
height: 20px;
display: block;
background: cornflowerblue;
width: 80%;
border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Once again, I would like the blue bar (div labelled bar or bar fill) to be positioned to the left inside the container.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use the `<center>` tag it is deprecated. When you remove it the problem will be probably gone

Comment: Ah, the `<center>` tag, my old friend.

Comment: try adding a float:left to .bar-fill

Comment: What's the best way to center all the content without using the <center> tag then?

Comment: To set the 'left' and 'right' margin of your content containing element to 'auto'

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `margin-left: 0px;` to `.bar-fill`

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
}
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.bar-fill {
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bar-fill"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but then i'd add `margin: auto;` too, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

The element is already left based on the code provided.

There is no `center` tag in your HTML and, in any event, the tag has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin:auto; /* center the container */
}
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.bar-fill {
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  width: 80%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bar-fill"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the container div is *inside* a `<center>` tag which cannot be removed then setting the `text-align` of the tag to `left` should have the desired effect.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c9mnx2w1/)